# How do I restore files removed from /usr/bin?

Tags: centos, process, proc, d-bus, readlink

**TL;DR** at the bottom.

---

**Background:**

The following occured on my CentOS 6.10 production server. I was using a browser based terminal program to run the program Midnight Commander which is a console-based file explorer. Unfortunately, the mouse support on this terminal was not setup correctly and I inadvertently applied a `mv` operation on several files inside the `/usr/bin` folder. The executables were moved into another directory. I was able to move the files back into `/usr/bin`, but I wanted to make sure things were restored.

---

**Test on Broken file:**

One of the excecutable programs that was moved is a program that is still running. It is called `dbus-daemon`. I was able to determine that this was process `847` on my machine.

When I run `readlink -f /proc/847/exe`, it doesn't return anything.

When I run the command `ls -l | grep exe` in the `/proc/847` folder I get

`lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 0 Dec  4 01:01 exe -> \ (deleted)/bin/dbus-daemon`

---

**Test on Working file:**

I decided to compare this to a normal executable that was not affected by the `mv` operation. I chose `chrond` to see if I got the same results. `chrond` is process `1187` on my machine.

When I run `readlink -f /proc/1187/exe`, it returns `/usr/sbin/crond`

When I run the command `ls -l | grep exe` in the  `/proc/1187/` folder, I get

`lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 0 Dec  4 01:01 exe -> /usr/sbin/crond*`

I hoped that by moving the files back, it would undo the damage. But the commands are not returning the expected results.

---

**TL;DR** My question is: If I move a executable out of `/usr/bin/`, can I move it back with no issues? If not, what else can I do to ensure that I can reboot my machine safely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why `proc` sees the binary as `deleted` is that you have moved it out of the file system. If you had moved it within the volume then `proc` would show the new path.

What you see is the normal situation after such a change. Does not mean there is anything wrong. Doesn't mean everything is right either... But it probably is.

Comment: Thank you for the additional insight about what the commands were telling me. For anyone else looking for a solution, I was able to find a process by which you can recover files deleted/removed from `/usr/bin` (or other folders) while they are running in memory. [https://www.sandflysecurity.com/blog/how-to-recover-a-deleted-binary-from-active-linux-malware/](https://www.sandflysecurity.com/blog/how-to-recover-a-deleted-binary-from-active-linux-malware/)